# mysql_real_escape_string out of database?

Tags: mysql

If I used mysql_real_escape_string just before putting a variable INTO a mysql table, do I need to use it again on any variables I take out of the table?

Comment: Goodness, no.  Please read the docs to understand *why* you're even using mysql_real_escape_string in the first place!

Comment: (You might, however, be interested in [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but if you're going to display your database output on a webpage you might want to filter it for html or javascript at that point.

Generally the way I look at filters, escaping, sanitization is like this. Before you use untrusted data for something, you make sure it's safe for that purpose. When INSERTing into a database you make sure it won't jack up your query. When sticking something on a webpage you make sure it doesn't contain anything that will deform your page or run unintended scripts.

Also if you use bound parameters you don't have to worry about mysql_real_escape_string. Many people including myself prefer doing it that way now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use it again if you are putting the variable back into the database. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

Well You needs to use this function only once if you used it before on one variable and using the same variable into insert you do not need to use this function again.