# mysql_real_escape_string when echoing out?

Tags: mysql-real-escape-string

I know I have to use mysql_real_escape_string when running it in a query, for example:

```
$ProjectHasReservationQuery = ("
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM reservelist rl
                            INNER JOIN project p on rl.projectid = p.projectid
                        WHERE rl.projectid = ". mysql_real_escape_string($record['projectid']) ."
                        AND restype = 'res'
                        ");
```

But how about echoing it out, like:

```
query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($query1 ))
{
    echo "".stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($record['usersurname']))."";
    // OR
    echo "".$record['usersurname']."";
}
```

Which one is it? Personally I think `echo "".$record['usersurname']."";`, since this is coming FROM a query and not going INTO. But want to be 100% sure.

(I am aware about PDO and mysqli)

Comment: You're not using any input when selecting * from users, so the option you provided will be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_real\_escape\_string out of database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443482/mysql-real-escape-string-out-of-database)

Answer (score 2):

> I know I have to use mysql_real_escape_string when running it in a query

Quite contrary, you **should not** use mysql_real_escape_string on a query like this.
It will do no good but leave you with false feeling of safety.

As you can say from the function name, it is used to escape strings, while you are adding a number. So, this function become useless, while your query still remains wide open for injection.

One have to use this function only to format quoted strings in the SQL query.
Thus you can conclude the answer from this rule: no, there is no point in using this function for output.

As for the protection, either treat your number as a string (by quoting and escaping it) or cast it using intval() function.

Or, the best choice, get rid of this manual formatting and start using placeholders to represent dynamical data in the query. it is not necessarily prepared statements - it could use the same escaping, but encapsulated in some placeholder handling function

Comment: I noticed that you got unbanned a little early

Comment: @RPM: early for what or whom?